# Satnav like directions embedding into a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geolocation

Is there a way of embedding a Sat-Nav geolocation type mapping into a website?Basically giving you turn by turn realtime directions.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBDlu.png)

I am aware that the Google Maps app has this functionality but I need this implementing into a website, any guidance would be great.

Thanks

Comment: You mean like this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel ?

Comment: Kind of but it needs to have the arrow displaying your location and orientation, just like a sat nav :)

Answer (score -1):

Google maps, not just the app, has this functionality.
You can use their [JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/)
You can find examples and documentation at their api.
For directions you will need to use their [directions service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)

> To use directions in the Google Maps JavaScript API, create an object
>   of type `DirectionsService` and call `DirectionsService.route()` to
>   initiate a request to the Directions service, passing it a
>   `DirectionsRequest` object literal containing the input terms and a
>   callback method to execute upon receipt of the response.
>
> The `DirectionsRequest` object literal contains the following fields:

```
{
  origin: LatLng | String | google.maps.Place,
  destination: LatLng | String | google.maps.Place,
  travelMode: TravelMode,
  transitOptions: TransitOptions,
  drivingOptions: DrivingOptions,
  unitSystem: UnitSystem,
  waypoints[]: DirectionsWaypoint,
  optimizeWaypoints: Boolean,
  provideRouteAlternatives: Boolean,
  avoidHighways: Boolean,
  avoidTolls: Boolean,
  region: String
}
```

> Initiating a directions request to the `DirectionsService` with the
>   `route()` method requires passing a callback which executes upon
>   completion of the service request. This callback will return a
>   `DirectionsResult` and a `DirectionsStatus` code in the response.

The following example will make a directions request and display the response in the `directionsPanel` div

```
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom:7,
    center: chicago
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
}

function calcRoute() {
  var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
  var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
  var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}
```

In the HTML body:

```
<div id="map" style="float:left;width:70%; height:100%"></div>
<div id="directionsPanel" style="float:right;width:30%;height 100%"></div>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12823561)

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov This I can understand but I with the question being as broad as it is I dont know if there are essential parts, or if I'd just be copying whole pages of googles api docs.